# Java TrayIcon.setToolTip() crashes JVM on String with 128 characters

Tags: java, user-interface, crash, tooltip, jvm-crash

while running my mp3 player, it crashed on some songs.
Looking into that, it turns out it's not the player itself, but the java TrayIcon class, when I call setToolTip(str) with str.length() == 128.

I wrote a short example to prove what happens:

```
package jc.javaexceptions;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.SystemTray;
import java.awt.TrayIcon;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;



public class Tray_setToolTip {

    // testing switches

    // if set to true, shows chrash screen
    // if set to false, app crashes quietly
    static private final boolean    SHOW_GUI_FAIL                   = true;

    // does not play a role if run in- or outside EDT
    static private final boolean    RUN_IN_SWING_DISPATCH_THREAD    = true;

    /**
     * Demonstrates, how setting a 128-char ToolTipText to a TrayIcon will crash the JVM
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws AWTException, InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        if (SHOW_GUI_FAIL) {
            final JFrame f = new JFrame("Test Window, fails at 128 chars ToolTipText length");
            f.setBounds(200, 200, 400, 400);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }

        // create tray image
        final int SIZE = 16;
        final BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(SIZE, SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
        g.drawLine(0, SIZE, SIZE, 0);

        // set up tray and tray icon
        final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(bi);
        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent pE) {
                tray.remove(trayIcon);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        tray.add(trayIcon);

        // works fine
        System.out.println("1 OK");
        trayIcon.setToolTip("Funny Test!"); // -> OK

        setTTT(trayIcon, 127); // try 127 -> OK
        setTTT(trayIcon, 129); // try 129 -> OK
        setTTT(trayIcon, 128); // try 128 -> CRASH // <--------------------------- CRASH

        // will not be reached!
        System.out.println("End reached!");
    }

    static private void setTTT(final TrayIcon pTrayIcon, final int pStringLength) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Tray_setToolTip.setTTT(" + pStringLength + ")");

        // construct bad-ass string
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < pStringLength; i++) {
            sb.append("1");
        }
        final String str = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("\tString len=" + str.length());

        if (RUN_IN_SWING_DISPATCH_THREAD) {
            //          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> pTrayIcon.setToolTip(str)); // cannot use invokeLater(), would allow the output of "End reached!"
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> pTrayIcon.setToolTip(str));
        } else {
            pTrayIcon.setToolTip(str);
        }
        System.out.println("\tOK");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Soooo... does this happen on your PCs too?
Or just on mine?
I run Oracle jdk-8u40-windows-x64 on an up-to-date Windows 7...

If it turns out this is a Java intrinsic bug, how should I proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes. Been fixed already. Had my Eclipse stuck on an old version of Java, current (1.8.0_151-b12) runs it without any problems.

Silly meeee